# Why do everytime I move a picture to a certain album, it always appears on top of the photos on an app like Instagram or LINE?

Tags: gallery, vivo

For example, I move a picture that I downloaded some times ago, from the "Download" album to "References" album, so it's not the latest photo I have. Then when I open Instagram to upload a picture, the picture I mentioned before is on the top of all photos, meanwhile usually the ones which are on the top should be the recent photos, right? My phone is Vivo V9. How should I fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you move files from one folder to other it changes date and time of a file when it was moved and I think there is no way to fix this